# Codename one : How to set image size in a Label when shown in Dialog

Tags: java, mobile, codenameone

I need to show a Dialog with: a title, 2 commands(Ok,Cancel) and an image, this is working fine ,but i need the image to be larger in the dialog and i tried:

```
image.scaled(x,y);
```

as well as :

```
imageLabel.setSize(new Dimension(x,y));
```

But none of them worked, my image is in resource file and i get it through :

```
com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.getGlobalResources().getImage("imageid");
```

My code is:

```
Image alertImage = com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.getGlobalResources().getImage(alertImageId);
alertImage.scaled(500, 500);
Command commands[] = {new Command("Aceptar"),new Command("Cancelar")};
Label lblAlert = new Label(alertImage);
lblAlert.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
Command result = Dialog.show(alertTitle, lblAlert, commands);
```

How can you control the size of an image shown in a dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
alertImage = alertImage.scaled(500, 500);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a guess?

Comment: It's an answer. You are scaling an image to x/y which is a position probably 0 by 0. Then you are doing `alertImage.scaled(500, 500);` which is wrong because you are discarding the result. I suggest putting more effort into the review @fanaghirocco